# Nginx proxy pass works for https but not http

Tags: nginx

I want to redirect HTTP traffic and HTTPS traffic to a backend Flask application and I have the snippet below in my nginx.conf which works for https but not for http

```
server {
listen 80;
listen 443 ssl;
ssl_certificate /usr/local/nginx/server.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /usr/local/nginx/server.key;

location / {
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_cache off;
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:5000;
        proxy_set_header   Host             $http_host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
}
```

Does anyone have any pointers?  Is there something obvious in the config file snippet or did I install Nginx wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed nginx on my Redhat16 machine from yum.  After I removed the contents of the etc/nginx/conf.d directory, everything worked as expected.  It seems something in that directory was overruling the http proxy_pass.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need a separate `server` block for HTTP. For example:

```
server {
listen 80;

location / {
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_cache off;
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:5000;
        proxy_set_header   Host             $http_host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
}
```

You would then remove `listen 80;` from the existing `server` block.

Comment: According to the Nginx documentation, you can have a single block. http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html